# select top 1 record per group in ms sql without using Max or Min

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know googling this question comes back a lot of solutions, but none of them apply to my situation.

I have a table such that:

```
CREATE TABLE [Batch](
    [batch_id]  [int]       NOT NULL, 
...(more columns)
    [date] [datetime]   NULL)
 CONSTRAINT [pk_Positions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   
[batch_id] ASC, 
...(more columns)
 )
```

1. `batch_id` and `date` has a one-on-one relationship. I.e., for a given batch_id, all dates are the same, for a given date, all batch_id are the same. (I know it's poor design. If I were to design the table I would probably create a separate table for batch_id and date)
2. there can be multiple records that have the same `batch_id`

Now I want to get a list of all distinct `date`s.

Since the table is very huge and `date` is not an indexed column,  I don't want to try anything like:

```
select distinct date from Batch
```

And for similar reasons, I have ruled out the option of creating a non-clustered index on `date`

Instead, I want to do something like:

```
select First(date) from Batch 
Group by batch_id
```

or

```
select Top 1 date from Batch 
Group by batch_id
```

but MS SQL doesn't provide `First()` function, and the latter one returns a "not in a aggregate function" error.

As far as I see based on my research, I should use `Min()` or `Max()` as an alternative to `First()`, such as:

```
select Max(date) from Batch 
Group by batch_id
```

However, since there can be sometimes over 100k records with the same `batch_id`, using `Min()` or `Max()` is not as efficient as just returning the first record without any comparison. So how can I optimize the last query to achieve better performance?

Comment: But top date from each group is not the same as all distinct dates. How do you justify that?

Comment: hi shree.pat18. sorry I didn't made myself clear. I have edited the post

Comment: So you don't really want the first record ordered by anything, just the first record in that group?

Comment: shree.pat18: yes exactly!

Comment: maybe it makes sense to create additional index (batch_id, date) and use min/max?

Comment: If you have a missing index it's a good idea to add this index.

Comment: Lashane, zespri: yes, adding an index is my first thought, but 1) this table is in production, 2)'[pk_Positions]' is wide, so the performance gain is not worthwhile for the trouble incurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create this function:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetDateForBatch_id
(
    @batch_id int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 [date]
    FROM dbo.Batch
    WHERE batch_id=@batch_id)
END
go
```

and then run this query:-

```
select 
    b.batch_id,
    dbo.GetDateForBatch_id(b.batch_id) AS [date]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT batch_id
FROM Batch) b
```

You should get optimal performance with the index strategy you have in place.

Comment: this seems to be the answer i am looking for. i will test it's performance tomorrow. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you say there's a one-to-one relationship between `batch_id` and `date` this will do the job:

```
SELECT DISTINCT batch_id, date FROM Batch
```

If it's not true, you can associate a row number to each record and retrieve only the first:

```
WITH BatchWithRowNum AS
(
    SELECT 
        * 
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY batch_id ORDER BY date)
    FROM Batch
)
SELECT * FROM BatchWithRowNum WHERE RowNum = 1
```

The third way of doing this which I expect to be faster than the row number approach is:

```
SELECT B.batch_id, T.MinDate AS date
FROM Batch B
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT B2.batch_id, MIN(B2.date) AS MinDate
    FROM Batch B2 
    GROUP BY B2.batch_id
) T 
ON B.batch_id = T.batch_id 
GROUP BY B.batch_id, T.MinDate
```

The following is not generally an efficient solution, but may have a better performance in your case because it only relies on the already existing index on `batch_id`:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT B.batch_id
    , date = (SELECT TOP 1 date FROM Batch B2 WHERE B2.batch_id = B.batch_id)
FROM 
    Batch B
```

If you have serious performance issues and adding index is not an option, none of the above will help you unless you narrow down the result-set with a `WHERE` clause. For example bring through a subset of batches with a certain set of `batch-id`s, or those in a specific `date` range.

Comment: Thank you. but performance wise both queries should be no better than using Max() and group by because it essentially still has to iterate thru all `date`, right?

Comment: Your suggestions will provide the correct answers.  A `DISTINCT` and an `OVER()` both have implicit sorts, however.  These will be the major CPU & IO consumers for each solution.

Comment: @Jimbo, I updated the answer and added another approach which may have a better performance in your situation. I think it'll produce a better performance than using a loop.

Comment: yes the last query looks neat. i will try it tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Much as it irks my SQL-karma to say so, I think this may be one situation where iterative processing is useful.  In pseudo-code:

```
declare #WorkingTable(batchID, date)
declare @CurrentBatchID = NULL
declare @BatchDate = NULL;

select top 1 
    @Current BatchID = batch_id,
    @BatchDate = [Date]
from Batch
where batch_id > -1  -- less than the smallest in the table
order by batch_id asc;

while @CurrentBatchID is not NULL
begin
    insert #WorkingTable values (@BatchID, @BatchDate);

    select top 1 
        @CurrentBatchID = batch_id,
        @BatchDate = [Date]
    from Batch
    where batch_id > @CurrentBatchID
    order by batch_id asc;
end

select * from #WorkingTable
```

Although there will be one table access per iteration it will be on the the clustered key with all the advantages that brings.  Still ugly, though.

If you intend to do this on a regular basis it would be better to create a look-up table with just batch_id and [Date] in it which is maintained by your ETL and purge processes.

Comment: yep i have hundreds of distinct batch_id in the table while each batch on avg contains tens of thousands of records. so using a loop might actually give better performance. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

--Just delete duplicate records -- best way yet
DECLARE @juvenileid int, @luCountyName varchar(40),@DispHearDate datetime,@vid int
set @vid = 0
declare db_cursor cursor for
SELECT  juvenileid, luCountyName,DispHearDate FROM #TEMP48 ORDER BY juvenileid
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @juvenileid, @luCountyName,@PlDt
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        BEGIN100:
        IF @vid = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @vid = @juvenileid
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
        IF @vid= @juvenileid
        BEGIN
            delete from #TEMP48 where juvenileid = @juvenileid
            and luCountyName =  @luCountyName
            and DispHearDate = @DispHearDate
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @vid = 0
            GOTO BEGIN100
        END
        END
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @juvenileid, @luCountyName,@DispHearDate
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve the readability of your answer for others by adding code tags. When editing your answer, highlight the block of code and click on the `{ }` button. This will ensure the website renders your code neatly when posted.